# Open UIDatePicker when UITextField is tapped from Custom Component

Tags: swift, swift3, uitextfield, uikit, uidatepicker

I have a custom `UIView` component that has a `UITextField`, `UIImageView` and another `UIView`.

I need to change the behavior of the `UITextField` to display a `UIDatePicker` when it's tapped. This is the code I'm trying to execute but for some reason the datePicker doesn't open when it's tapped:

```
class TextFieldWithFeedback : UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var underlineView: UIView!

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        self.textField.inputView = datePicker
    }
}
```

When I used the same code on my ViewController (code below) it worked:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    customView.textField.inputView = datePicker
}
```

Now, this solution works but it's not ideal because I have 8 of those custom views and it would be better to set it once instead of 8 times.

**Which method of the View class should I use to set the datePicker up?** Since draw doesn't work.

Also, how can I attach a function to modify my `UITextField` value when the user picks a date?

Comment: You need to keep a reference of your date picker

Comment: Just declare it as a property of your view controller

Comment: @LeoDabus so instantiate DatePicker on ViewController and set it on each customView? To use on the draw method

Comment: Do not misuse `draw` for this! Oh, the horror, the horror.

Comment: @matt help me out then, which one should I use :)

Comment: Use something else than `UITextField`, there is no point to have it since you don't need input.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve it like this:

```
//To control whether or not to use the DatePicker, easily customized on the Storyboard
@IBInspectable var useDatePicker: Bool = false

@IBAction func textFieldEditing(_ sender: UITextField) {
    self.textFieldStartedEditing(sender: sender)
}

func textFieldStartedEditing(sender: UITextField) {
    if useDatePicker {
        let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = .date

        sender.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.datePickerValueChanged), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    }
}

func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY"
    self.textField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
}
```

All of the code above inside my customView class.

If anyone else is having trouble with this and needs help feel free to comment, I promise I'll be more helpful than the people who commented on the question :)

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is addTarget to your Textfield and then in a method Show the UIPickerView

```
self.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.openDatesPicker), for: .touchDown)
```

You should also set tag for your textfield so you can identify it later in the code. Also you should implement this method which stops the keyboard from showing up

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField.tag == 2 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: That solves only half of my problem, the big problem is that the datePicker doesn't open